# Complex ORM query in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

This is my User

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    username = models.CharField(null=False, unique=True, max_length=255)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And this is my Quiz model,

```
class Quiz(Base):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='quizzes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    winners = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='quizzes_won')
    losers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='quizzes_lost')
```

I want to query all quizzes that an user has not played, thus winners and losers does not contain user id. How do I do this.
Sorry I'm new to django.

Comment: Not played means Quiz with no winners and no losers? right?

Comment: @Lemayzeur yes exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `.exclude(..)` here and as criterion that the `User` is in the `winners` or `losers` relation. So:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Quiz.objects.exclude(Q(winners=user) | Q(losers=user))
```

Here [**`Q`** [doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) is an object that encapsulated a certain predicate. By using the "or" operator `|` we thus specify as condition that `winners` contains `user`, or `loser` contains `user`. We exclude thus `Quiz`zes that satisfy at least one (or both) of these criteria.

This results with a MySQL backend in a query like:

```
SELECT `quiz`.*
FROM `quiz`
WHERE NOT (
    (  `quiz`.`id` IN (SELECT U1.`quiz_id` AS Col1
                       FROM `quiz_winners` U1
                       WHERE U1.`user_id` = 123)
    OR `quiz`.`id` IN (SELECT U1.`quiz_id` AS Col1
                       FROM `quiz_losers` U1
                       WHERE U1.`user_id` = 123)
    )
)
```

(where `123` is in fact the `id` of the `user`)

Comment: @W QQ what's Q, could you please point me to the documentation

Comment: @MelissaStewart:: see edit (with reference to the documentation).

Comment: @MelissaStewart this answer is better to use instead of two `exclude`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exclude`:

```
Quiz.objects.exclude(winners=my_user).exclude(losers=my_user)
```

Comment: QQ, can I do ```Quiz.objects.exclude(winners=my_user, losers=my_user)```

Comment: @MelissaStewart: no, that would mean quizzes where `user` is both a `winner` and `loser`.

Comment: So effectively my syntax means AND, and yours means OR, right?

Comment: @MelissaStewart: indeed, if you put multiple conditions (separated with comma), by default Django uses "and" logic. Technically speaking there is nothing wrong if they had used "or" logic, but somehow they decided to use "and" (non of the two is inherently better).